# l = list(map(lambda x: x+n, l)) what does this do

Tags: python, list, lambda, generator

```
l = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]

print("list : ", l) 
n = int(input('N: ')) 
l = list(map(lambda x: x+n, l)) 
print("new list : ", l)
```

`l = list(map(lambda x: x+n, l))` how does this code works?

Comment: Read the docs about "map", "lambda" and "list" if not done yet. Edit the question to describe then what you think the line does and what exactly you don't understand.

Comment: These kind of code which handles lots of stuff is called as oneliners. In this case you need to understand `lambda` and `map`. Please also look for the term generators in python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lambda` use to create function (like `def`, but it's inline)

`lambda x: x+n` mean you insert `x` as parameter and it will return `x+n`

For example

```
f1 = lambda x: x+5
print(f1(10))
```

result is `15`

You can see more here [link](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lambda.asp)

`map` use to apply function to every element in that `list` or list like such as `tuple, array`

see more here [link](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_map.asp)

so in your case, if you input `n=1`, result is `l=[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]`

Answer (score 0):

This code add n to each element of the list. Read more about map and lambda function on https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map and https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/operators/lambda.html